# What is the Lebesgue Measure of the set of numbers in (0,1) that contain 100 consecutve 4's?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This comes from S.Axler's Measure Theory Graduate Textbook.

I am struggling with this problem and I really do not have any idea how to tackle it.

I know this is a Borel Set. I did it as the countable union of intervals $I_n$, where infomrally, $I_n =  \cup_{A}[0.A444...44, 0.A444...45$) where $A$ is any $n$ digit numbe and $4$ is written 100 consecutive times. It should contain all the required numbers.

What I have noticed is that it is dense in the $(0,1)$ interval and it is an uncountable set (take any decimal expansion of a number in $(0,1)$ and add 100 consecutive  4's at the beggining of that decimal expansion). Using the proof of a Borel set to calculate the measure and adding the requirement that $A$ should not contain 4's gave me a lower bound: $10^{-99}$. My intuition is that the Lebesgue measure should turn out to be  1, but it may not be the case

Comment: Have you heard about the cantor set? or more specifically, a fat cantor set? that might aid your intuition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Comment: The fact that almost all real numbers are absolutely normal is proved in Chapter 9 of Hardy & Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, fourth edition.

Comment: oh sorry i think my comment only applies to the set of all decimals where the first 4 that appears is the beginning of a 100 4 sequence. *that* will be the complement of a fat cantor set. in your situation i think you just get the complement of an ordinary "thin" cantor set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability theory answer.  The digits in the base $10$ expansion are i.i.d random variables with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Suppose I roll a 10-sided die repeatedly.  What is the probability that I never get $100$ consecutive $4$'s?  Of course that probability is zero by the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result).  So (taking the complement) the set of decimals that contain $100$ consecutive $4$'s has measure $1$.

---

Requested, more complete explanation.

Divide into blocks of length $100$.  Let $B_1$ be the first $100$ digits, let $B_2$ be the second $100$ digits and so on.  Write $T_j$ for the event "Block $B_j$ consists of $100$ consecutive $4$'s".  These events are independent since the blocks are disjoint.  We claim

$$
\mathbb P\left(T_j\text{ occurs for infinitely many } j\right) = 1 .
\tag 1$$

For any $j$ we have $\mathbb P(T_j) = 10^{-100}$.  The exact value is not important, only that it is nonzero. It is the same for all $T_j$.  The series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb P(T_j)$ diverges to infinity.  So by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we get $(1)$.

Comment: I am having trouble using the First Borel Cantelli to show this. I tried toy examples like an infinite coin toss model and the event that 3 heads in a row will appear but am struggling to find the right sets. Can you provide a hint?

Comment: It is what that web page calls the "second Borel-Cantelli lemma."  But this "first" and "second" terminology is not universally used.  I will add more detail.