# measure of the set consisting of those numbers in (0,1) whose decimal expansion contains hundred consecutive 4s

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It's a problem from Sheldon Axler;s Measure Theory book.
What I did so far is-
E= set of all numbers in (0,1) that have decimal expansion containing hundred consecutive 4s 
$A_{n}$ = set of numbers in (0,1) such that the hundred consecutive 4s start from nth position after decimal point and before the nth position there is no hundred consecutive 4s in that expansion.
Countable union of $A_{n}$ is the set E.
So E is borel set. But I am struggling to find the measure of this set.
I tried calculating the measure of the set of points which don't contain any hundred consecutive 4s in their decimal expansion. But there also I got stuck.
I have seen the similar question has been asked here before. But I could not totally understand the probability approach to the problem.
[What is the Lebesgue Measure of the set of numbers in (0,1) that contain 100 consecutve 4's?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686462/what-is-the-lebesgue-measure-of-the-set-of-numbers-in-0-1-that-contain-100-con)

Comment: As a toy problem, do you know how to find the the measure of the set of numbers in $(0,1)$ that contains a $4$ somewhere in the decimal expansion? ... what if instead of base 10, the number was written in base googol ($10^{100}$)?

Comment: yes, I know that.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to think about the complement of this set, i.e. the set of all numbers $x \in (0, 1)$ that *don't* have $100$ consecutive $4$'s lurking somewhere in their decimal expansion.

**Lemma.** For any base $b \geq 3$ and digit $d \in \{0, 1, ..., b-1 \}$, the Lebesgue measure of the set $$S_d := \{ x \in (0, 1): x \text{ contains no digit } d \text{ in base } b \}$$ is zero.

*Proof of lemma.* The set of all points that don't have $d$ as their first digit has measure $1 - 1/b$. The set of all points that don't have $d$ as their first or second digit has measure $(1 - 1/b)^2$. The set of all points that don't have $d$ as their first, second, third, ..., or $n$th digit has measure $(1 - 1/b)^n$. So $$\mu(S_d) \leq (1 - 1/b)^n \text{ for all } n,$$ which implies $\mu(S_d) = 0$.

Now think about some particular bases and digits that might apply to this problem, like, oh, I don't know, $b = 10^{100}$, $d = 4(10^{100}-1)/9$....

Comment: I may be missing something here, but it seems that this approach underestimates the measure as the hundred 4s need may be 'split' between two digits, so some extra work is needed?

Comment: It ends up not making a difference. If there's a hundred consecutive fours somewhere in $x$'s decimal expansion, that means $x \in [(0.1)^k S_d]^c$ for some $0 \leq k \leq 99$. So while not all counterexamples live in $S_d$ itself, every counterexample must live in one of the $100$ measure zero sets $(0.1)^k S_d$ for some $0 \leq k \leq 99$, hence the set of counterexamples still has measure zero.

Comment: I'm not getting it, too much wine maybe. Sadly it is clear to me from a Markov chain argument, but not the above :-(.

Comment: @copper.hat One way to reason this: If the expansion contains no occurrence of 100 consecutive 4's, then certainly the first block of 100 digits is not all 4's, and also the second block of 100 is not all 4's, and so on. This argument yields an *upper* bound for the measure of the set of interest, but by independence the upper bound is zero.

Comment: @grand_chat Thanks & sorry, I should not drink and derive.

Comment: @copper.hat Let's say there's a block of a hundred consecutive fours, but it's split up between two "googol digits". Then I can just shift the decimal point of $x$ $n$ places to the left, $0 < n < 100$, until that block *is* a googol digit. Shifting $x$'s decimal point $n$ places left is the same as multiplying by $(0.1)^n$, so we have $(0.1)^n x \in (S_d)^c$, or $(0.1)^{100} x \in (0.1)^{100-n} (S_d)^c$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just an elaboration.

Let $A$ be the set of sequences that do not contain a run of one hundred $4$s.

Let $A_k$ be the set of sequences such that at least one of $x_k,...,x_{k+99}$ is not $4$. Note that $P A_k = 1-{1 \over 10^{100}} <1$.

It is clear that $A \subset A_1 \cap A_{101} \cap A_{201} \cap ...$ and so  we have $PA \le P(A_1 \cap A_{101} \cap \cdots \cap A_{100n+1} )$ for any $n$.

By independence we have $P(A_1 \cap A_{101} \cap \cdots \cap A_{100n+1} ) =(P A_1)^n$ and so $PA = 0$.

Comment: To the upvoter, the above was incorrect when you upvoted it. Sorry :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an argument for which you can fill in the details.

Look at the decimal expansion of $x\in (0,1)$ and break the expansion into contiguous blocks, each of length $d=100$. Let $B_k(x)$ be the function that maps $x\in(0,1)$ to the $k$th such block.

Let $S$ be the set of all sequences of $d$ decimal digits, so $S$ has $10^d$ elements. Argue that for any $s_1,\ldots,s_n \in S$ (with the $(s_k)$ not necessarily distinct):
$$
\lambda\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n\left\{x\in(0,1):B_k(x)=s_k\right\}\right)=\frac1{10^{dn}}.\tag1
$$
In words, the set of numbers whose decimal expansion begins with $0.s_1s_2\cdots s_n$ has Lebesgue measure $1/10^{dn}$. It follows that for any subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of $S$, we have
$$
\lambda\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n\left\{x:B_k(x)\in A_k\right\}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\lambda\left(\left\{x:B_k(x)\in A_k\right\}\right).\tag2
$$
(Proof: Express the set on the LHS of (2) as a disjoint union of sets of the form appearing in the LHS of (1).) In probabilistic terms, this establishes that the $B_k$ are *independent random variables*.

To finish the proof, argue that the *complement* of your set $E$ is a *subset* of the set
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^n\left\{x: B_k(x)\ne 44\cdots 4\right\}.\tag3$$
Compute the measure of (3) using (2), giving an upper bound for $\lambda(E^c)$. This upper bound holds for every $n$, so we are done.